# Setting className shortcut

Tags: javascript, shortcut

Is there a know one-liner for setting the `className` attribute in JavaScript? I mean where you don't have to worry if there is already some class(-es) defined or not.

The shortest I could think of, is

```
var objDemo = document.getElementById("demo");
objDemo.className = "newclass " + (objDemo.className || "");
```

This wouldn't die if the current `className` is undefined, however it leaves me with a trailing space. Would that be a problem for current browsers?

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('demo').classList.add('newclass');
```

You can read more about this API on the Mozilla Development Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList

Note that Internet Explorer versions before 10 are not yet supported, but a polyfill is given on the page referenced above.

Comment: Thank you, hadn't even heard of this new property!

Comment: Note, you need to make sure that all of your target browsers support this. http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist

Comment: It's supported as of IE10 (http://caniuse.com/classlist), so technically all current browsers are OK, even though IE9 support would be nice.

Comment: @epascarello: Sure; if not I think it is always better to polyfill the missing support than to invent a new custom API.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to first check if there is **already** a class with the name you are adding,
or just move it to the end of the class list if it is found.

This function works in most browsers without any polly filling:

```
function addClass(element, c){
    var c1= element.className.replace(RegExp('\\s*'+c+'\\b\\s*'), '');
    element.className= c1? c1+' '+c:c;
}
```